# WebGL/THREE radians go from 0 to 1.57 back to 0 to -1.57 etc. how can I tell where I am in the cycle

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi it appears that radians go up and down and then up again, I"m trying to get the direction from a camera, to animate a flyover, and it seams to give me repeating numbers when the camera turns more than 90 degrees on either side. what am i missing.

```
function camDirection(camera){
  rad = camera.rotation.y;
  console.log(camera.rotation);
  console.log(rad);
  var x = Math.sin(rad);
  var z = Math.cos(rad);
  return new THREE.Vector3(x, 0, z); 
}

var direction = camDirection(ctx.camera);        
ctx.camera.position.z += 10 * direction.z;
ctx.camera.position.x += 10 * direction.x;
```

Comment: _Sine_ and _cosine_ have a period of _2π_, it looks like you're missing a pie. You'll probably need to show where `camera.rotation` is being set and the issue will probably be forgetting to use radians to taking too small a remainder.

Comment: the camera rotates accurately on the Y axis, the problem is that the position changes are aimed at their counterpart in the -90 to +90 degree region. for example rotating 180 degrees is accurate for the camera, but will move backwards not forwards

Answer (score 1):

You can get the direction the camera is looking like so:

```
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(); // create once

...

camera.getWorldDirection( direction );
```

---

If all you want to do is move the camera forward, you can do so like so:

```
camera.translateZ( - 10 ); // forward is down the negative-z axis for a camera
```

three.js r.71